# Circle Universe fanfic where Tris went sorta power-mad after the Pirate Battle and Nico had to talk her down

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, circle-universe

Help me find a fanfic where Tris went sorta power-mad and started to call herself Stormbringer or Stormbreaker, or something. Whatever name she thought of while trying to stop the tides or something, and Nico had to talk her down... possibly from a cliff that she was using to control storms from?

And she got turned into that state after the Pirate Battle or something?

It's not recent, it existed at maybe around 2010?

I tried Fanfiction.net, but I can't find it, although, I might just not be using the correct filters.

I remember the description talking about her taking the wrong lesson from her attempt to halt the waves, but I might be wrong?

It might be from one of the more focused sites, for Tamora Pierce Fanfic? I think it was plain, white background, blue accent things?

---

I know that I've read at least a short fic, about the tree that Numair inadvertently turned into a man, when he turned a man into a tree...

Comment: [This](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5540912/1/A-Learning-Experience) is on FFN, has something about lessons and halting the tides in the description, was published in 2009 but the rest doesn't match. Is it possible you read it too and conflated two stories? Can we rule this one out? :)

Comment: @Jenayah - Nope, doesn't feel at all familiar.

Comment: Eh, the search continues then :)

Comment: @Jenayah - Do you know any Tamora Pierce fanfic focused sites? ... Like http://fiefgoldenlake.proboards.com/board/41/tortall-fanfiction ... Although, that site doesn't look familiar. ... Maybe AO3... It's old enough? ... I also remember some story about them getting drunk in a barn... But that might be canon.

Comment: I don't know either the focused sites, nor the source material, actually :D I tried googling around in the hopes I might hit it on the off chance